# Disable SWRevealViewController bouncing on addGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to use `SWRevealViewController` in my app which is sliding menu library, but i needed to edit the library with one option and i will explain as follows.
when using `addgestureRecognizer` and opening the sliding-menu by keep on holding from the left to the most right and then left it,it bounce too much outside to the right then close the menu. i just need to disable this option from the library, just like to open to its normal limit without bouncing.

The link on GitHub is here : 
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Line 648 in `SWRevealViewController.m` and change it from :

```
_rearViewRevealOverdraw = 40.0f;
```

to :

```
_rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0f;
```

Comment: This is also available as a property on the `SWRevealViewController` itself. You can set it in one of your view controllers (`self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0f;`) after importing `SWRevealViewController.h`.